# How to make text bigger in all input areas (email signup, comment box, recipe index page dropdown) in CSS?

Tags: css, font-size, text-size

Website: https://olivesfordinner.com/

Looking for CSS code that will achieve the following:

1. When typing in email on homepage to sign up for newsletter, making that text appearbigger. It's so small.
2. When leaving a comment on a recipe post (example: https://olivesfordinner.com/toasted-muesli-recipe/), how to make the text bigger as the reader is typing within it. Again, this text is so small.
3. How to make the text appear bigger in the drop-down text boxes on the left-hand column. They are so tiny! https://olivesfordinner.com/recipe-index/

Thank you!

I have googled lots of CSS code, but nothing I've found has affected the text size in these areas at all.

Comment: Use your browser's devtools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is setting the font-sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue 1

This will increase the font size for your `Sign up to get new recipes via email.` element

```css
.enews-form > #subbox {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}

.enews-form > input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}
```

## Issue 2

This will fix this issue

```css
#commentform textarea#comment, #commentform input#author, #commentform input#url {
    font-size: 13pt !important;
}
```

## Issue 3

This will fix the dropdown lists

```css
select#cat, select#archives-dropdown-2 {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

## Notice

you can add each to the custom css for each page or globally as such

```css
/* Issue 1 Solver */
.enews-form > #subbox {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}
.enews-form > input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 12pt !important;
}

/* Issue 2 Solver */
#commentform textarea#comment, #commentform input#author, #commentform input#url {
    font-size: 13pt !important;
}

/* Issue 3 Solver */
select#cat, select#archives-dropdown-2 {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
```

Do know that this CSS code will only effect their respective elements, unlike the css code by others' answers.

Comment: Thanks very much, this seems to have solved the issue!

Comment: yes, sorry about that. It's marked now!

Answer (score 0):

The font size is setting with this

```css
input, select, textarea {
    ....
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
    ....
}
```

This sets the font size of the `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements to `11px`.

### Fix

**1** - You can update `font-size` into required size

```
input, select, textarea {
    ....
    font-size: 20px;
    ....
}
```

**But note**, this will effect all the  `input`, `select` and `textarea` elements in the website

**2** - You can create a new class with the required `font-size`

```
.font-size-20 {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

add this class with elements you need bigger font size, like

```
<input class="font-size-20" id="email" name="email" type="email">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following selectors and change the `font-size`

For Header email subscription, drop-down text and comment:

```
input, select, textarea{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

For search:

```
input, select, textarea{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Footer email subscription:

```
.footer-widgets .enews-widget input{
    font-size: 20px;
}
```